# SCSS maps incorrectly images to css

Tags: css, sass

Hello I have problem with image mapping scss to css. The problem are paths. I get error 404 because of that CSS file is one level higher in hierarchy than scss component. So it should be

`background-image: url("../images/sparkling.jpg");` What to do to make mapping correct.

scss:

```
.modal__image--1 {
  background-image: url("../../images/sparkling.jpg");
  background-position: center;
}
```

css:

```
.modal__image--1 {
  background-image: url("../../images/sparkling.jpg");
  background-position: center;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just set the path to background-image: url("../images/sparkling.jpg"); in scss.